# Filtering random products in Woocommerce using array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

As a noob in PHP, I'm trying to filter out products in Woocommerce using array. I managed to only filter them by category.

I also would like to filter out ones, that are out of stock and drafts (by array, if possible).

And one more question, how do I add in `'product_cat'` more than one category? When I want to filter **hoodies** and **shirts** for example?

For the in stock product I have tried following code, which doesn't work:

```
'meta_value' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'get_stock_status',
            'value' => 'outofstock',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
    )
```

Not sure, how to check if they are drafts or not.

This is my code:

```
<ul class="products">
 <?php
 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'orderby' => 'rand',
 'posts_per_page' => 1,
 'product_cat' => 'hoodies'

 );
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
 woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
 endwhile;
 } 

 wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if products are in stock by passing arguments to `meta_query`

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'instock'
    )
)
```

Checking for multiple categories with `category__and` you'd need to pass an array of category IDs

```
'category__and' => array(1,2) // select categories with array of IDs
```

And to check for posts/products that are published you need to pass `publish` to `post_status`:

```
'post_status' => 'publish' // select products that are published
```

Together it might look something like this (Note: *Not tested*)

```
 $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'product',
      'orderby' => 'rand',
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'category__and' => array(1,2), // replace these with your cat IDs
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => '_stock_status',
               'value' => 'instock'
           )
       )
  );

  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
       endwhile;
  } 

  wp_reset_postdata();
```